# Transversality if and only if a regular value

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, transversality

Let $f:M^{m}\rightarrow N^{n}$ a differential application and $S^{k}$ a submanifold of $N$. We say that $f$ is transversal to $S$ in $p\in f^{-1}(S)$ if $df_{p}(T_{p}M)+T_{f(p)}S= T_{f(p)}N$. If $S^{0}=\{c\}$, show that $f$ is transversal to $c$ if and only if $c$ is a regular value of $f$.

---

My work:

---

Suppose that $f$ is transversal to $c$, so:
\begin{eqnarray}
 df_{p}(T_{p}M)+T_{f(p)}S= T_{f(p)}N
\end{eqnarray}
if $v\in T_{f(p)}N$, then:
\begin{eqnarray}
 v=\lambda_{i}\sum_{i} df_{p}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}\right)+\beta_{j}\sum_{j}
\frac{\partial}{\partial u_{j}}
\end{eqnarray}
where $T_{f(p)}S=span\left\{\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial u_{j}}\right\}$ and $T_{p}M= span\left\{\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}\right\}$, so, every $v\in T_{f(p)}N$ can be write in terms of $df_{p}$ and $df_{p}:T_{p}M\rightarrow T_{f(p)}N$ is a surjection (this conclusions isn't clear for my right now).

---

By other hand, Suppose that $c$ is a regular value of $f$, so:
\begin{eqnarray}
 \forall p\in f^{-1}(c), \hspace{0.5cm} df_{p}:T_{p}M\rightarrow T_{f(p)}N 
\end{eqnarray}
is a surjection between $T_{p}M$ and $T_{f(p)}N$, so, analogous to before case, $\forall v\in T_{f(p)}N$:
\begin{eqnarray}
 v&=&\lambda_{i}\sum_{i}df_{p}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}\right)\\
\end{eqnarray}
but I can't express it in span's terms of $df_{p}$ and $T_{f(p)}S$. I'll appreciate advices or ideas to continue in both cases.

Comment: If $S$ is a point, you should know what $T_{f(p)}S$ looks like.

Comment: It's the empty set? Sorry I'm little confused.

Comment: It will be a zero dimensional subspace in $T_cN$, which is......